# Can I add commercial apple juice to the apple juice from my trees which I have pressed when making cider?

Tags: fermentation

I can I add some good quality natural apple juice which I have purchased
to the apple juice from my own trees when making cider?
If so when shoudl it be added, before or after fermentation?

Comment: Why not? What are you concerned about?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can add juice from your own trees. Add it before you add the yeast otherwise it will ferment again when you add the new juice since you are adding new sugar and the yeast will consume it.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your purchased juice does not contain Sorbate or Sulfites in the ingredients, if possible, because that can cause problems with fermentation.

If not possible, there is a solution:

**Sulfites** will "evaporate" after a few hours if left in contact with air, so let the juice breathe for a few hours before adding it to your batch; most sulfites will be gone.

**Sorbate** usually is used prevent the start of fermentation (it will not stop a vigourous fermentation), so if you start the fermentation of your batch, you may add juice containing Sorbate after a day of fermentation to your batch without harm.

If your purchased juice contains sulfites/sorbates, wait to have a vigorous fermentation before adding it to your batch.

If not, you may add the juice before or during fermentation.

Comment: Sulfites shouldn't have too much effect on wine yeast unless they are strong enough to smell. Sorbate is a different matter but I have never seen it in apple juice.